# Conflict between copy constructor and constructor with std::any

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm testing the c++17's std:any functionality, which seems to solve many of the type-problems my project has. Nevertheless I have reach a dead-end...

Take a look at this example (working) code:

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(const Test &o) : name(o.name), data(o.data) { std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl; };
    Test(std::string name, const char *data) : name(name), data(data) { std::cout << "string-constchar constructor" << std::endl; }
    Test(std::string name, std::any data) : name(name), data(data) { std::cout << "string-any constructor" << std::endl; }
    explicit Test(std::any data) : data(data) { std::cout << "any constructor" << std::endl; }

    std::string name;
    std::any data;
};

int main()
{
    Test t1("test", "test 2");
    Test t2("test", 57);
    Test t3 = t1;
    Test t4(97);
    // std::vector<Test> vt;
    // vt.push_back(t3);

    return 0;
}
```

If we compile and run this code under g++9 we would find what probably many of us may expect:

```
string-constchar constructor
string-any constructor
copy constructor
any constructor
```

It is interesting to see how the compiler could perfectly recognize the difference between the `std::any` and the `const char*` and call the correct constructor.

However, it presents many issues handling the copy-constructor. As an example, if the `explicit` keyword is removed from the constructor with the param `std::any`, it would immediately conflicts with the copy constructor and the compiler (clang-9 / g++9) would report a compile error.

The same happens when the 2 commented lines (the vector lines) are uncommented. The push_back/emplace_back may call the copy constructor at some point, that, again, triggers this compile-error related to conflict between copy-constructors.

I'm quite lost on why the compiler can't handle the copy constructor case (but others without any problem). Any ideas on why this is happening? Any possible work-around?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have something like this:

```
struct X {
    X();
    X(std::any);
};

X a;
X b = a;
```

When we're trying to figure out what to do with the copying of `b`, we have the copy constructor, but we also have `X(std::any)` which is viable if `X` is copy constructible which, to check that, we have to recursively check to see if `X` is constructible with an  `X` which again gets us into the `X(std::any)` constructor.

Now, interestingly, libc++'s implementation of `std::any` works here, while libstdc++'s does not. This seems to depend entirely on when the relevant type traits are instantiated and how the implementation handles caching them - I'm not sure. See also [gcc bug 90415](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90415) which tracks this.

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much for this (quick) response!
Reading that gcc bug seems to be what you have said. It should be fixed on future g++9.4, or at least that's the milestone. I'll wait and follow it then.

As temporal work around I could make it work adding this:
`template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, Test>::value>::type>`

Thanks mate!